# The limit of the maximum of a sum of sines

Tags: limits, definite-integrals, summation, maxima-minima, trigonometric-integrals

I've recently stumbled upon the following problem from [Brilliant](https://brilliant.org/):

> Compute the following:
>
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\max_{x\in[0,\pi]}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin(kx)}k$$
>
> Options:
>
> 1. $\displaystyle\int_0^\pi\frac{\cos^2(x)}{x^2}~\mathrm dx$
> 2. $\displaystyle\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}~\mathrm dx$
> 3. $\displaystyle\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin(x)}x~\mathrm dx$
> 4. $\displaystyle\int_0^\pi\frac{\cos(x)}x~\mathrm dx$

Already by looking at it, it doesn't make sense for 1 or 4 to be correct, since they both diverge. Instinct then tells me the answer should be 3, since $\sin^2$ doesn't appear in the problem. However, I haven't been able to get to it.

By differentiating, I can find potential maxima as follows:

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin(kx)}k=\sum_{k=1}^n\cos(kx)=\csc\left(\frac x2\right)\sin\left(\frac{nx}2\right)\cos\left(\frac{(n+1)x}2\right)$$

Obviously the sum is zero on the boundaries, so we are not interested in them. Aside from them though, there are a lot of points to consider. My suspicion is that the maximum occurs at $x=\frac\pi{n+1}$ since this point has every term in the summand being positive. Furthermore, if this is the case, then we can rearrange the original sum into a Riemann sum, getting 3 as the answer.

How may we continue? Or perhaps this is the wrong approach...?

---

One may also note that answer choice 2 is less than answer choice 3, and we can see 3 is a possible answer choice, meaning that if this exists and is one of the answer choices, it must be the 3rd one.

Comment: Which piecewise function has this Fourier series representation for $0 \le x\le \pi$ ? Perhaps this helps. The maximum is around $1.5$

Comment: @Cesareo This is a finite sum, and forcing it to be an infinite series doesn't give me any of the answer choices anyways.

Comment: But the limit for $n\to\infty$?

Comment: Letting $n\to\infty$ and then taking the $\max_{x\in[0,\pi]}$ results in $\frac\pi2$ if I did it right, which does not agree with any of the answers provided. Since the possibility of the maximum being at $\frac\pi{n+1}$ yields a Riemann sum and one of the answers provided strongly implies to me that that is not the correct answer.

Comment: The right result is option $3$ which is equal to $\frac{\pi}{2}+0.89489872236(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2})$. The second term is due to the Gibbs phenomenon.

Answer (score 2):

The series

$$
S_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\sin(k x)}{x}
$$

represent in the Fourier sense, limiting approximations for the periodic piecewise function

$$
f(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}-\frac x2, \ \ \ 0\le x \lt 2\pi
$$

So we have

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\max_{0\le x\le \pi}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin(k x)}{k}\right) = \frac{\pi}{2}+\delta
$$

here $\delta$ is due to the Gibbs phenomenon which can be calculated as

$$
\delta = 0.08948987223608363511601442291245487...\times \pi
$$

where $\pi$ is the discontinuity jump value.

This result is the same of

$$
\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\sin x}{x} dx = 1.851937051982466...
$$

Attached a plot with $n = 10$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**The following proof is the main parts of [$0<\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin kx}{k}<\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4002979/proof-of-inequality-0-sum-k-1n-frac-sin-kxk-int-0-pi-frac-sin-x) posted by me.**

Let
$$f_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin kx}{k},\quad x\in[0,\pi],$$
we can deal with as follows:
consider
$$f'_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos kx=\frac{\cos\frac{n+1}{2}x\sin\frac{n}{2}x}{\sin \frac{x}{2}},x\in(0,\pi),$$
then
$$f'_n(x)=0\iff \cos\frac{n+1}{2}x\sin\frac{n}{2}x=0,\quad x\in(0,\pi),$$
the critical points contained in $(0,\pi)$ of $f_n$ are listed below:
$$\text{critical points}:\frac{\pi}{n+1}<\frac{2\pi}{n}<\frac{3\pi}{n+1}<\cdots.$$
Remark：The number of critical points of $f_n$ is $n$ if $n$ is odd, and is $n-1$ if $n$ is even.
It can be shown that
$$f_n\left(\frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{n+1}\right)}{k}
=\max_{x\in[0,\pi]}f_n(x).$$

We get that:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{n+1}\right)}{k}
=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{n+1}\right)}{\frac{k}{n+1}}\to \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx.
\quad (\text{Riemann sum})$$