# Proof of inequality $0<\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin kx}{k}<\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx$。

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, inequality, solution-verification

> I give a proof of a question in AoPSonline
> https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h492604_sum_k0nfracsinkxk

$\textbf{What I want to know is: is there some mistake in my proof, any help will welcome!}$

The LHS is just Fejer-Jackson inequality.
Let
$$f_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin kx}{k},\quad x\in[0,\pi]$$
For the RHS, we can deal with as follows:
consider
$$f'_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos kx=\frac{\cos\frac{n+1}{2}x\sin\frac{n}{2}x}{\sin \frac{x}{2}},x\in(0,\pi),$$
then
$$f'_n(x)=0\iff \cos\frac{n+1}{2}x\sin\frac{n}{2}x=0,\quad x\in(0,\pi),$$
the critical points contained in $(0,\pi)$ of $f_n$ are listed below:
$$\text{critical points}:\frac{\pi}{n+1}<\frac{2\pi}{n}<\frac{3\pi}{n+1}<\cdots.$$
Remark：The number of critical points of $f_n$ is $n$ if $n$ is odd, and is $n-1$ if $n$ is even.
It can be shown that
$$f_n\left(\frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{n+1}\right)}{k}
=\max_{x\in[0,\pi]}f_n(x).$$
Note that: $\frac{\pi}{n+1}$ is the smallest critical point of $f_n$.
We claim that:

(1) sequence $\left\{f_n\left(\frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)\right\}$ is strictly increasing;

(2) $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{n+1}\right)}{k}
          =\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx;$$
(3) $$f_n(x)<\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx\quad x\in(0,\pi).$$

Due to $f_n$ is strictly increasing on $[0,\frac{\pi}{n+1}]$ ,
we know
$$f_{n+1}\left(\frac{\pi}{n+2}\right)>f_{n+1}\left(\frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)
=f_{n}\left(\frac{\pi}{n+1}\right).$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{n+1}\right)}{k}
=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{n+1}\right)}{\frac{k}{n+1}}\to \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx
\quad (\text{Riemann\ sum})$$
So we conclude:
$$f_n(x)\leq f_n\left(\frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)<\sup_{n}f_n\left(\frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{n+1}\right)}{k}
          =\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx.$$

Comment: Thank you for your post! I believe this proof already perfect!